# Where to find product name in Prestashop Database structure

Tags: prestashop

i'm developing a very simple (for newbie user) back end for prestashop, and i would like to know where to find the product’s images name uploaded.. 
I know they are into “img/p” directory. But i don’t know: 
1. In which database table they are .. linked
2. Why they are called (for example): 1-18-small.jpg … why “1-18” instead “1” (his productid) ? what that number means ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since image names are language dependents, you will find them in image_lang table.

About filenames, the pattern is : productId-imageId-size.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Full table structure you can see here:

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Fundamentals

Names of the files:

In my case viwth ver. 1.5 is: **img/p/3/0/3/1/3031-home_default_1.jpg**

So its very easy to understand name is repeating folder structure.

**img/** - image
**p/** - product
**3/0/3/1/**  i think is so many because in case you have may images for one product.

3031 folder structure and then **home_default_1.jpg** or another sizes with different names in same folder, you can see just browse this folder.